# Replacing deprecated "defined(@array)" in a ternary operation

Tags: perl

I have the following code which needs to be corrected, as `defined(@array)` is deprecated in the latest Perl.

```
my @inputs = (
    ( defined @{$padSrc->{inouts}} ? @{$padSrc->{inouts}} : () ),
    ( defined @{$padSrc->{inputs}} ? @{$padSrc->{inputs}} : () )
);
```

I don't want to move to `if ( @{ $padSrc->{inouts} } )` kind of approach, as that will increase my line count.

Comment: *"I don't want to move to `if ( @{ $padSrc->{inouts} } )` kind of approach, as that will increase my line count"* What kind of design principle is that? Just delete all the newlines if it worries you so much. It's a disgraceful attitude.

Answer (score 5):

`defined(@array)` has never done what it looks like it does. It always just returns whether `@array` is non-empty.

```
perl5.10.1 -E 'say defined(@foo)'                # ""
perl5.10.1 -E '@foo=(); say defined(@foo)'       # ""
perl5.10.1 -E '@foo=(42); say defined(@foo)'     # "1"
perl5.10.1 -E '@foo=(undef); say defined(@foo)'  # "1"
```

Anywhere that you test `defined(@array)` in your code, you can replace it with
`@array != 0` or `scalar(@array)` and your code will work exactly the same (plus or minus some deprecation warnings).

As `if (condition) ...` or `(condition) ? expr1 : expr2` or `while (condition)` always evaluate `condition` in scalar context, the `scalar` is optional in these constructions, and you can replace, say `if (defined(@foo))` with `if (@foo)`.

Answer (score 3):

You do not say what Perl version you use, so the following may work (if using Perl 5.10 or later) or not (if you are stuck with older versions), and since it is not very clear why you used `defined` in the first place:

```
 my @inputs = (
    @{$padSrc->{inouts} // []},
    @{$padSrc->{inputs} // []}
);
```

or even simpler:

```
my @inputs = map { @{$padSrc->{$_} // []} } qw/inouts inputs/;
```

Comment: While this isn't equivalent to the original code, this is probably what the original author of that code was *trying* to do. In any case, this solution is not wrong and elegantly concise.

Answer (score 2):

That's much more concisely written this way

```
my @inputs = ( @{ $padSrc->{inouts} }, @{ $padSrc->{inputs} } );
```