# check if sub returned undef

Tags: arrays, list, perl, undefined

Contrived example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $myval = 'a';
my @result = my_sub($myval);
if (@result) {
        print "DEFINED\n";
}
my ($res1, $res2, $res3) = @result;
print "res1=$res1, res2=$res2, res3=$res3\n";
sub my_sub {
         my $myval = shift;
        if ($myval eq 'a') {
                return undef;
        }
        return ("a","b","c");
}
```

How do I check if sub returned undef?

or

How do I check if sub did not return undef?

Comment: Use `return ()` or just `return` instead of `return undef`.

Comment: See also [Replacing deprecated “defined(@array)” in a ternary operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48809624/2173773) and [Define(@array) is Deprecated](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node=1077762)

Comment: Use just `return;` It will automatically return`undef` in scalar context and `()` in list context. Adding an argument to the return may cause hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`return undef` in list context returns list of one element, which is `undef`.

```
 @result = my_sub($myval);
 if (@result == 1 && !defined($result[0])) {
     warn "my_sub() returned undef";
 } else {
     print "my_sub() returned data\n";
 }
```

That said, a list with one `undef` element is almost never what you want. See [How do I return nothing from a subroutine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604584/how-do-i-return-nothing-from-a-subroutine) You will generally just want to `return` with no arguments. In scalar context, that returns `undef` and in list context it returns an empty list.

```
sub my_other_sub {
     my $myval = shift;
    if ($myval eq 'a') {
            return;
    }
    return ("a","b","c");
}
...
@result = my_other_sub($arg1);
$result = my_other_sub($arg2);
if (@result == 0) {     # or: if (!@result) ...  or: unless (@result) ...
    warn "my_other_sub(arg1) did not return any data";
} else {
    print "my_other_sub(arg1) returned data\n";
}
if (!defined($result)) {
    warn "my_other_sub(arg2) did not return any data";
} else {
    print "my_other_sub(arg2) returned data\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend, as others have, to use `return`, or the more explicit `return ()`. This returns an empty list. However, since the example is contrived, we can't be sure that an empty list isn't an otherwise valid return.  If it is a valid return, or it might reasonably be so one day, then you have other options which, IMO, are less ideal but can be more flexible.

An obvious one is to use `die`, as zdim suggested, but that can be relatively heavy-handed. It may actually be really what you want - if this situation really isn't supposed to happen, die is perfect as it might cause your program to abort if you don't wrap the failure in an `eval`.

Another alternative is to have your sub return an array ref instead of a list. And then you can return `undef` directly, your caller would be able to check that easily enough: `my $result = my_sub(...);`.  Other uses of that array would just need to go through a dereference, e.g., `my ($res1, $res2, $res3) = @$result;`.  This is probably my preference when a simple `return ()` cannot suffice.  Bonus points in that only the reference is passed back, not the whole list.  Consider doing this even when an empty list isn't valid but the list can be very large.

Other options also abound, although those are probably the simplest. You could, for example, return a hash (or array) with one entry indicating success/failure and another with the array. You could return success/failure as the first element (your contrived example would `return (1, "a", "b", "c")` and you'd shift that first element off to see if it was successful or not). You could embed your return in an object that encapsulated all that.  Of these, only the object one would I give serious consideration to, but it would greatly depend on the rest of the architecture, and would be very rare.

Answer (score 0):

A subroutine returns a list of scalars in list context which you use, then assigned to variables.  So if you return an `undef` from it the `$res` variables are going to be `undef` -- first assigned `undef` and others unassigned (while the array `@result` will have one element, an `undef`)

```
perl -Mstrict -wE'
    my $val = shift; 
    sub t { return undef if shift eq "bad"; return qw(a b) }; 
    my ($v1, $v2) = t($val); 
    if (not defined $v1 and not defined $v2) { say "undef" } 
    else { say "$v1, $v2" }
' bad
```

The first `shift` takes the value off of `@ARGV`, so vary input of "*bad*" to see other cases.  This can be written in more compact and clearer ways if we knew how it's used.

I appreciate that this is a test example, but it is still too convoluted, allowing for tricky edge cases; for example, your first case won't work since `@result` is *not "false"* (empty list), what the code tests for, as it does have one element, which is `undef`.

For such "special" returns either use [return](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/return.html) with no arguments or throw a [die](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html), in situations you consider exceptional. For context-aware returns see [wantarray](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/wantarray.html).